# Biapplicative and Bimonad?

Tags: haskell, monads

Haskell's `Data.Bifunctor` is basically:

```
class Bifunctor f where
  bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d
```

I could find a `Biapply` as well. My question is, why isn't there a complete bi-hierarchy (bierarchy?) like:

```
class Bifunctor f => Biapplicative f where
  bipure :: a -> b -> f a b
  biap :: f (a -> b) (c -> d) -> f a c -> f b d 

class Biapplicative m => Bimonad m where
  bibind :: m a b -> (a -> b -> m c d) -> m c d

  bireturn :: a -> b -> m a b
  bireturn = bipure

bilift :: Biapplicative f => (a -> b) -> (c -> d) -> f a c -> f b d
bilift f g = biap $ bipure f g 

bilift2 :: Biapplicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> (x -> y -> z) -> f a x -> f b y -> f c z
bilift2 f g = biap . biap (bipure f g)
```

Pair is an instance of these:

```
instance Bifunctor (,) where
  bimap f g (x,y) = (f x, g y)

instance Biapplicative (,) where
  bipure x y = (x,y)
  biap (f,g) (x,y) = (f x, g y)

instance Bimonad (,) where
  bibind (x,y) f = f x y
```

And types like...

```
data Maybe2 a b = Fst a | Snd b | None
--or 
data Or a b = Both a b | This a | That b | Nope
```

...would IMO have instances as well.

Are there not enough matching types? Or is something concerning my code deeply flawed?

Comment: How would you define `bipure` for `Maybe2 a b`? Neither `Fst` nor `Snd` is canonical, leaving `None`, which is hardly useful. I reckon most nontrivial candidate types for these classes have similar problems, but it's just a guess. At least `Or` looks reasonable.  Good question.

Comment: Also, how would you define `bijoin`?

Comment: From practical point of view, I'd say the reason why these type classes are not used is that they have very little interesting instances. Consider how many instances `Bifunctor` has. Then `Biapplicative` or `Bimonad` would have even less (possible 0). Other than that, it's certainly an interesting question. Have you tried to construct some complete instances of those suggested type classes?

Comment: The `bifunctors` library that defines `Bifunctor` does have a `Biapplicative` class, but it doesn't define any laws that `bipure` and `<<*>>` should obey, analogous to the ones defined for `pure` and `<*>`. It defines a few instances: your `(,)`, one for `Const`, and for some types roughly isomorphic to them. Instances for higher-arity tuples arbitrarily(?) require the left-most types in the product to be monoids, so that they can simply be accumulated by `<<*>>`.

Comment: (The fact that applicative functors are strong lax monoidal functors probably suggests that the monoid restriction for n>2-tuples is not arbitrary, but I don't know if "strong lax monoidal bifunctor" is a thing.)

Comment: You can re-write `Maybe2 a b` as `Maybe (Either a b)`, and `Or a b` as `(Maybe a, Maybe b)`.

An interesting type is `These a b = This a | That b | These a b`, which cannot easily be re-written.

Comment: I think your `Bimonad` is incorrect, mostly because `join` can't be implemented by it.
After all, that is the category theory definition of a monad: `join` and `return`.
This would also stop `(,)` from being a member: There isn't a function `join :: ((a, b), (a, b)) -> (a, b)` unless you want to impose a `Monoid` constraint, which isn't allowed for monads anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A monad in category theory is an endofunctor, i.e. a functor where the domain and codomain is the same category. But a `Bifunctor` is a functor from the product category `Hask x Hask` to `Hask`. But we could try to find out what a monad in the `Hask x Hask` category looks like. It is a category where objects are pairs of types, i.e. `(a, b)`, and arrows are pairs of functions, i.e. an arrow from `(a, b)` to `(c, d)` has type `(a -> c, b -> d)`. An endofunctor in this category maps pairs of types to pairs of types, i.e. `(a, b)` to `(l a b, r a b)`, and pairs of arrows to pairs of arrows, i.e.

```
(a -> c, b -> d) -> (l a b -> l c d, r a b -> r c d)
```

If you split this map function in 2, you'll see that an endofunctor in `Hask x Hask` is the same as two `Bifunctor`s, `l` and `r`.

Now for the monad: `return` and `join` are arrows, so in this case both are 2 functions. `return` is an arrow from `(a, b)` to `(l a b, r a b)`, and `join` is an arrow from `(l (l a b) (r a b), r (l a b) (r a b))` to `(l a b, r a b)`. This is what it looks like:

```
class (Bifunctor l, Bifunctor r) => Bimonad l r where
  bireturn :: (a -> l a b, b -> r a b)
  bijoin :: (l (l a b) (r a b) -> l a b, r (l a b) (r a b) -> r a b)
```

Or separated out:

```
class (Bifunctor l, Bifunctor r) => Bimonad l r where
  bireturnl :: a -> l a b
  bireturnr :: b -> r a b
  bijoinl :: l (l a b) (r a b) -> l a b
  bijoinr :: r (l a b) (r a b) -> r a b
```

And similar to `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)` we can define:

```
  bibindl :: l a b -> (a -> l c d) -> (b -> r c d) -> l c d
  bibindl lab l r = bijoinl (bimap l r lab)
  bibindr :: r a b -> (a -> l c d) -> (b -> r c d) -> r c d
  bibindr rab l r = bijoinr (bimap l r rab)
```

### Relative monads

Recently, [relative monads](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/Relative_Monads.pdf) have been developed. A relative monad doesn't need to be an endofunctor! If we translate from the paper to `Bifunctor`s in Haskell, you get:

```
class RelativeBimonad j m where
  bireturn :: j a b -> m a b
  bibind :: m a b -> (j a b -> m c d) -> m c d
```

Which defines a monad relative to the bifunctor `j`. If you pick `j` to be `(,)` you get your definition.

The laws are the same as the monad laws:

```
bireturn jab `bibind` k = k jab
m `bibind` bireturn = m
m `bibind` (\jab -> k jab `bibind` h) = (m `bibind` k) `bibind` h
```

The first law prevents `Maybe2` from being an instance, because `bibind` has to be able to extract both values from the result of `bireturn`.

Comment: PS. Your `Biapplicative` class is correct I think. Biapplicative functors seem to match monoidal functors from `Hask x Hask` to `Hask`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why there's two separate types `l` and `r`. Wouldn't it be easier to have them be the same? Say `class (Bifunctor m) => Bimonad m` with an `instance Bimonad Either where bireturnl = Left; bireturnr = Right; bijoin = either id id` (`bibind = either`)?

Comment: You could do that, but then you don't have a monad in the category theory sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(category_theory)

Comment: If `l ~ r`, is `bijoinl = bijoinr`? Also, is `bireturnl = bireturnr`? (presumably not)

Comment: @SjoerdVisscher I don't quite follow why the superclass constraint of `Bimonad l r` is `(Bifunctor l, Bifunctor r)` instead of `Biendofunctor l r`, with the morphism mapping `bifmap :: Biendofunctor l r => (a -> b, c -> d) -> (l a c -> l b d, r a c -> r b d)` that you described earlier.

Comment: Oh I see, there's an isomorphism between `(a, b) -> (x, y)` and `((a, b) -> x, (a, b) -> y)`.