# join function for two-kinded monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to get a better understanding of monads.
So I'm trying to write return, join, and bind implementations for several monads.

However when coming to two-kinded monads, I'm kind of confused

```
join :: m (m a) -> m a
```

`m (m a)` Implies monad wrapped inside of monad, but what value is implied if using two-kinded monads.
For example with the State Monad: `s` or `a`? What would the correct signature of join for the State Monad look like?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "two-kinded" Monad. All Monad instances are of kind `* -> *`.

Comment: Like function application, type constructors associate left. So if you have `type Foo a b c d`then e.g. `Foo Int Char Bool` would have kind `* -> *` and you could define `instance Monad (Foo Int Char Bool)`. You can write types with redundant parens if you want, like `:: (((Foo Int) Char) Bool) Baz`

Comment: @ReinHeinrichs Read "two-kinded data types that have a Monad instance"

Comment: @hgiesel Is "two-kinded data types that have a Monad instance" a blog post or something? If so, you should give us a link; Google doesn't turn up anything when I try.

Comment: So to be clear, we don't have `instance Monad State where ...` since `State` has kind `* -> * -> *`. It is `instance Monad (State s) where ...`

Comment: Maybe look into [Biapplicative and Bimonad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556314/biapplicative-and-bimonad)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The state monad type is declared as `State s a`;
it only unifies with `m a` if `m ~ State s`.

```
join :: State s (State s a) -> State s a
```